# BlueStacks Apps

Tags: applications, backup, restore, bluestacks

so I have been playing on Bluestacks for a little over a year now and I had to update it; but when I did I encountered a bug or something; just I just kept getting the load screen I reported it a few times. ( I could still go to settings but that was it )

Eventually I backed everything up (all my data and apps) and uninstalled it, then reinstalled but when I reinstalled it auto went to Bluestacks v3.

I really don't mind using whatever Bluestacks they bring out BUT I can not find out how to "restore" my backup onto the new Bluestacks

how do I get my apps and data from those apps back; I have looked this up multiple places but most seem to be directed at the older verisons of Bluestacks

please help! I bought (yes paid real money) for some of these apps

over 400$ worth (over time) ;v;

Answer (score 0):

- **Starting with an assumption that you have backed up the data via copying BlueStacks and BlueStacksSetup folder from C:/ProgramData.**

Some steps you have to follow:

1. Enable Hidden files in Windows 7/8/8.1/10, see [here](https://www.technipages.com/show-hidden-files-windows).
2. Uninstall any BlueStacks version if installed without deleting the
   data or copy the backed up data in any other drive/folder.
3. After Installation, go to C:/ProgramData and Copy those backed up
   folders "BlueStacks and BlueStacksSetup"
4. Then install BlueStacks (Any version you want) and it will
   load/restore all your data/apps.

Note that **"C"** here is your windows drive.

- **Restoring Backup made using Bluestack itself**

1. Copy UserData folder to C:/ProgramData/BlueStacks and overwrite existing.
 
 2. Restart BlueStacks

Done.
**Note** - If there's no BlueStacks folder in ProgramData, create one.

Comment: I used the built in BlueStacks Backup

Comment: Can you share a screenshot to show what type of files are there & in what format?

Comment: http://sta.sh/0127h5ejskh0

Comment: the files in Android are vdi

Comment: Userdata has all my apps stuff

Comment: I don't know much about Game Manger it has a lot of various types of files

Comment: Editing the anwser.